# How to remove a scalar structure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have this code that filters through files and loads them to create this weird cell (2D inside a 2D?)array. I just need a vector of all these numbers in the end. Is there a way to get rid of these layers and condense it down, whether in the loop or after the fact?

```
slopes = dir('*Slope.m');%find all the files containing the name slope
num = numel(slopes);
file = cell(1,num); %Preallocate
for k = 1:num
    file{k} = slopes(k).name;   %taking name from file and making list
    final{k}=load(file{k}) %loading contents of each file
end 

ans= 
    final = 
    {
      [1,1] =

        scalar structure containing the fields:

          Slope = 
          {
            [1,1] =

              -1.1921
              -1.0496
              -1.5440
              -8.0588
              -1.5505
              -2.0916
              -1.8253
               1.5526
               2.8496

          }

      [1,2] =

        scalar structure containing the fields:

          Slope = 
          {
            [1,1] =

              -1.2797
              -1.0386
              -2.7018
              -2.4564
              -1.5939
              -2.6885
              -1.2366
               2.0501

          }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a link to your data?  I wouldn't mind checking to see whether or not what I write is correct.

Comment: Sorry @rayryeng I do not own the rights to the data so I cannot release them to you. The slopes files range from -2 to 2 with 10^15 accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this was answered several times but it's just a common one liner in matlab:

```
flat_final = [final{:}]
```

To make the answer more complete you could use `horzcat`, `vertcat` and `reshape` to finetune your results.

The technical term for your task is *flatten* so you might find many more snippets if you search for it.

Comment: This merely turns the cell array into a structure array which becomes harder to deal with since I am using Octave which doesn't have struct2* functions. I have tried using `horzcat`, `vertcat`, and `reshape` to no avail. I also looked into _flatten_ but couldn't find anything relevant. Is there a particular post you may be able to direct me to?

Comment: You will need to repeat for every layer. for the struct it should look similar: `flatter_final = [ flat_final(:).Slope ]` (don't have matlab at hand now so can't test it). Unfortunately I don't know octave so I can't really say if the syntax is implemented. As for links - there's a few scripts at [matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=flatten&term=flatten) you might look into.

Comment: I added both your pieces of code to the loop and it got rid of the structure and made a simple cell array. Now to play with `vertcat` and `reshape` to get a vector. Thanks a lot!